# VueJS 3 Blank page after setup router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, symfony6

I have a problem when i comment this line

```
import router from './routes';
```

The code works and i have the Hello world message

I have no error in console

app.js

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';

import App from "./components/home.vue";

//import router from './routes';

const app = Vue.createApp(App);

//app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

routes.js

```
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Home from './components/home';

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:[
        {
            path:'/',
            name:'home',
            component: Home
        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

home.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    methods: {}
}
</script>

<template>
    Hello world
</template>
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    
        {% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can you help me please

Comment: Does your index.html have I'd #app?

Comment: Yes (edited with index.html)

Comment: It seems you have not added script tag in html. You have to link the bundled js in index.html.

Comment: It's already linked with Webpack Encore (i use Symfony) and the code works without the line import router from './routes'; (edited again)